# Алгоритм вывода лучшей комбинации

Tags: python, алгоритм

Нужно решить задачу смысл которой заключается в выводе лучшей комбинации значений, на основе уже имеющихся данных. Например, у нас есть таблица с уроками и переменная "продуктивность", которая будет меняться в зависимости от расположения уроков, определенного их наличия и.т.д. Таким образом, нужно основываясь на предоставленных данных воспользоваться алгоритмом и получить "лучшее расписание", при котором значение "продуктивности", было бы максимальным.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком направлении идти. Пробовала разобраться каким образом подобное можно было бы совместить(??) с ML, но ничего толкового не нашла.

---

Пример:

Таблица со столбцами: 

**урок1, урок2, ..., урок8, продуктивность**

Столбцы с уроками, могут принимать значения от одного, до возможного количества уроков вообще (то есть просто: 1, 2, 3; каждое число будут обозначать какой-то урок). В продуктивность же записываются значения в процентах.

После, модель "обучается" на данных, и выдает лучшую комбинацию при которой значение переменной "продуктивность" будет равна 100% (ну или, самому максимальному значению).

Comment: Для начала нужно определиться с тем, как считать эту самую "продуктивность".

Comment: @Эникейщик Все данные будут предоставлены уже в готовом виде (это можно сказать, просто наблюдения, которые нужно будет обработать).

Comment: Я и говорю - для начала нужно решить, как обработать, чтобы получить ту самую продуктивность. Вы же хотите получить какой-то численный результат, вот вам нужно и определить, как именно его вычислять на основе ваших данных. Вывести формулу, так сказать.

Comment: Что то мне подсказывает, что у вас типичная задча о ранце https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5

Comment: @Mike Сейчас постараюсь разобраться. Спасибо!

Comment: приведите минимальный пример ввода и желаемого вывода

Comment: @jfs Спасибо, исправила!

Comment: @ЭллНейгебауэр конкретные цифры покажите

Comment: @jfs Конкретных цифр у меня нет.

Comment: @ЭллНейгебауэр для примера придумайте минимальный ввод и соответствующий вывод иначе чересчур расплывчатая формулировка.

Comment: Вы так и не ответили на самый главный вопрос: как на основе порядка уроков рассчитывается продуктивность? Что продуктивнее: математика, история, биология или история, математика, биология? И почему?

Comment: Если место конкретного предмета в линейке уроков влияет на продуктивность, то задачу о рюкзаке тут не получиться применить.

Comment: И второй вопрос - как определяется продуктивность - как число (в каких пределах), в рангах (например 1- непродуктивно, 2 - лучше, 5 - самая продуктивная) или в виже сравнения (последовательность "история, мат, физкультура" производительнее "физкультуры, истории, биологии")